# How to tag records with filename, imported to pandas dataframe from multiple csv files?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of csv files I need to import into a pandas dataframe.

I have imported the filepaths as a list, FP, and I am using the following code to read the data:

```
for i in FP:
    df = pd.read_csv(i,index_col=None, header=0).append(df)
```

This is working great, but unfortunately there are no datetimestamps or file identifying attributes in the files. I need to know which file each record came from.

I tried adding this line, but this just returned the filename of the final file read:

```
for i in FP:
    df = pd.read_csv(i,index_col=None, header=0).append(df)
    df['filename'] = i
```

I can imagine some messy multi-step solutions, but wondered if there was something more elegant I could do within my existing loop.

Comment: what attributes do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None).assign(filename=f) for f in FP], 
               ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Works Perfectly. You also fixed a bug I overlooked, I forgot the importance of ignore_index=True. Will note in my original question.